# Laravel voyager: I accidentally deleted the menu tools

Tags: laravel, voyager

I accidentally deleted the menu tools from Voyager. How can I get it back?

Comment: if you in dev environment you can do composer update

Comment: Didn´t work. The weirdest is that my online app also lost the menu Tools!

Comment: your project is a repo and your edit was sent to the same repo your production is related with

Comment: I don´t remember to send any commit to the online repo... but that´s not the issue... I just can´t get the Tools menu back.
And can´t reorder the admin menu eighter... something blows up and don´t know how to fix

Comment: have you edited the default menu if so just get back the online repo to a commit where it was fine and pull the project from it

Comment: You know what? I read the voyager route file and then re created the menu Tools back.
It is working like a breeze!

Comment: wow happy for you bro :D